# Background Job in powershell while writing to STDOUT/Console

Tags: powershell

I have GUI.exe application that sometimes prints messages back to the console it was started in. In git-bash for example I would kick it off like this `gui.exe &`. This will place it into the background but allows it to write  back to the shell. In PowerShell I can do the following:

```
& `C:\pathTo\gui.exe` | Out-Default
```

This will write back to the console but will block the shell.

I can also do the following:

```
Start-Job {& `C:\pathTo\gui.exe` | Out-Default}
```

But in this case I would have to call `Receive-Job` (maybe with -Keep) to extract the messages.

Is there a way to have the process both print to `Out-Default` as well as run in the background. I'm also not sure why I have to force the pipe to | Out-Default as both in cmd.exe and bash it can print the messages. PSversion is `5.0.10586.117`.

**Edit**
As per the suggestion of @metix:
`Start-Process -NoNewWindow 'C:\pathTo\gui.exe`
This does put it into the background but doesn't print back to the console.
If I add `-RedirectStandardOutput C:\tmp\testout.txt`, then this writes to testout.txt. Is there a way to `RedirectStandardOutput` to the console?

Answer (score 1):

this should run the process in the background and also prints to console:

`Start-Process -NoNewWindow 'C:\pathTo\gui.exe'`

Comment: Thanks! It does run in the background, but fails to print to the shell.

Comment: hmm indeed...I was able to reproduce the behavior with a c# application...but something like `Start-Process -NoNewWindow ping.exe google.de` works...strange

Comment: Thanks for checking. I was about to mock up something in F# myself. I'm somewhat fuzzy on how PS treats itself, and the application running inside it. It would seem that it starts ping.exe inside a cmd.exe. However my application is a .NET Gui application and doesn't show a cmd.exe. Hence -NoNewWindow actually has no effect.  Maybe if I recompile not to hide a window PS might be able to capture its output but that would be a bit of kludge.  It certainly knows about the output as I can extract it with a `Receive-Job`.